# How to handle CLI subcommands with argparse

Tags: python, argparse, subcommand, subparsers

I need to implement a command line interface in which the program accepts subcommands.

For example, if the program is called “foo”, the CLI would look like

```
foo cmd1 <cmd1-options>
foo cmd2
foo cmd3 <cmd3-options>
```

`cmd1` and `cmd3` must be used with at least one of their options and the three `cmd*` arguments are always exclusive.

I am trying to use subparsers in argparse, but with no success for the moment. The problem is with `cmd2`, that has no arguments:

if I try to add the subparser entry with no arguments, the namespace returned by `parse_args` will not contain any information telling me that this option was selected (see the example below).
if I try to add `cmd2` as an argument to the `parser` (not the subparser), then argparse will expect that the `cmd2` argument will be followed by any of the subparsers arguments.

Is there a simple way to achieve this with `argparse`? The use case should be quite common…

Here follows what I have attempted so far that is closer to what I need:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='Functions')
parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', help='...')
parser_1.add_argument('cmd1_option1', type=str, help='...')

parser_2 = subparsers.add_parser(cmd2, help='...')

parser_3 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd3', help='...')
parser_3.add_argument('cmd3_options', type=int, help='...')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all subparsers are *never* inserted in the namespace. In the example you posted if you try to run the script as:

```
$python3 test_args.py cmd1 1
Namespace(cmd1_option1='1')
```

where `test_args.py` contain the code you provided (with the `import argparse` at the beginning and `print(args)` at the end).

Note that there is no mention to `cmd1` only to its argument. *This is by design*.

As pointed out in the comments you can add that information passing the `dest` argument to the [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) call.

The usual way to handle these circumstances is to use the [`set_defaults`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) method of the subparsers:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='Functions')
parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd1', help='...')
parser_1.add_argument('cmd1_option1', type=str, help='...')
parser_1.set_defaults(parser1=True)

parser_2 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd2', help='...')
parser_2.set_defaults(parser2=True)

parser_3 = subparsers.add_parser('cmd3', help='...')
parser_3.add_argument('cmd3_options', type=int, help='...')
parser_3.set_defaults(parser_3=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Which results in:

```
$python3 test_args.py cmd1 1
Namespace(cmd1_option1='1', parser1=True)
$python3 test_args.py cmd2
Namespace(parser2=True)
```

In general different subparser will, most of the time, handle the arguments in completely different ways. The usual pattern is to have different functions to run the different commands and use `set_defaults` to set a `func` attribute. When you parse the arguments you simply call that callable:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser(...)
parser_1.set_defaults(func=do_command_one)

parser_k = subparsers.add_parser(...)
parser_k.set_defaults(func=do_command_k)

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.func:
    args.func(args)
```

Comment: I take issue with the  'never inserted'.  Simply give the 'add_subparsers' a `dest`.

Comment: @hpaulj You are right. However I, personally, never used that. As I said it's much more command to have different handling functions for different subparsers so using `set_defaults` is a better solution. Only for the most simple situations you want to use the `dest` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The subparser identity can be added to the main `Namespace` if the `add_subparsers` command is given a `dest`.

From the documentation:

> However, if it is necessary to check the name of the subparser that was invoked, the dest keyword argument to the add_subparsers() call will work:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')
>>> subparser1 = subparsers.add_parser('1')
>>> subparser1.add_argument('-x')
>>> subparser2 = subparsers.add_parser('2')
>>> subparser2.add_argument('y')
>>> parser.parse_args(['2', 'frobble'])
Namespace(subparser_name='2', y='frobble')
```

By default the `dest` is `argparse.SUPPRESS`, which keeps `subparsers` from adding the name to the `namespace`.