# How can I build sub-commands to bundle scripts that should also work independently?

Tags: python, setuptools, argparse

I am currently working on a research project (my bachelors thesis) for handwriting recognition. I wrote a lot of Python scripts so far and I would like to make them useful for other people. So I created a project on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hwrt/

Currently, only 2 executable scripts are there: `backup.py` and `view.py`. When it is installed via `pip` I can call them, so that works:

```
$ backup.py --help
usage: backup.py [-h] [-d FOLDER] [-s] [-o]

Download raw data from online server and back it up (e.g. on dropbox)
handwriting_datasets.pickle.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d FOLDER, --destination FOLDER
                        where do write the handwriting_dataset.pickle
                        (default: /home/moose/Downloads/write-math/archive
                        /raw-datasets)
  -s, --small           should only a small dataset (with all capital letters)
                        be created? (default: False)
  -o, --onlydropbox     don't download new files; only upload to dropbox
                        (default: False)

$ view.py --help
usage: view.py [-h] [-i ID] [--mysql MYSQL] [-m FOLDER]

Display a raw_data_id.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i ID, --id ID        which RAW_DATA_ID do you want?
  --mysql MYSQL         which mysql configuration should be used?
  -m FOLDER, --model FOLDER
                        where is the model folder (with a info.yml)?
```

I got this via `scripts` in `setup.py`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'hwrt',
    'version': '0.1.19',
    'author': 'Martin Thoma',
    'author_email': 'info@martin-thoma.de',
    'packages': ['hwrt'],
    'scripts': ['bin/backup.py', 'bin/view.py'],
    'url': 'https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt',
    'license': 'MIT',
    'description': 'Handwriting Recognition Tools',
    'long_description': """A tookit for handwriting recognition. It was
    developed as part of the bachelors thesis of Martin Thoma.""",
    'install_requires': [
        "argparse",
        "theano",
        "nose",
    ],
    'keywords': ['HWRT', 'recognition', 'handwriting', 'on-line'],
    'download_url': 'https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt',
}

setup(**config)
```

However, I would rather want them to be called like this:

```
$ hwrt backup --help
(just what came before for 'backup.py --help')
$ hwrt view --help
(just what came before for 'view.py --help')
$ hwrt --help
(a list of all sub-commands)
```

I know that this can be done with sub-commands and argparse. However, this would mean I had to create a new script where I bundle all commands for argparse. But I also would like the scripts to work independently. It just feels more logically for me to adjust command line parameters that are only important for `backup.py` only in `backup.py` and not in another file.

Is there a way to adjust my scripts so that they "discover" the scripts in the bin folder and add all of them as sub-commands?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for using using `parents`.

For example, lets assume both of your scripts create a `parser` object when loaded (or have a function that creates a parser):

```
import argparse
from backup import parser as backup_parser
from view import parser as view_parser

if __name__=='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
    # or use the parser.setdefault() as described in the documentation
    backup = subparsers.add_parser('backup', add_help=False, parents=[backup_parser])
    view = subparsers.add_parser('view', add_help=False, parents=[view_parser])
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This should print the appropriate helps.  `args.cmd` will identify the subcommand, and the other attributes will be the respective arguments.  The `backup` subparser will be a clone of the parser imported from `backup.py`.  (I haven't tested this script so there may be some typos or bugs, but it gives the general idea.)

[How to handle CLI subcommands with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216875/how-to-handle-cli-subcommands-with-argparse) discusses a couple of ways of handling subcommands.

`Ipython` uses `argparse` to handle both the main interface, and many of the magic commands.  It populates its parsers with arguments and values from the config files.  That way a large number of parameters can be set either with default configs, customized configs, or on the command line.

Comment: I've just tried it and at a first glance it seemed to work. I had to move the `parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)` and related stuff from backup.py and view.py outside of the `if __name__=='__main__':` block, but that would be ok I guess. However, when I wanted to execute `hwrt backup -whatever parameter` it did not execute. I guess the problem is that the "executing" part was still under `if __name__=='__main__'`. So I completely removed `if __name__=='__main__'` from view.py and backup.py. But then `./hwrt --help` did only show `backup.py`.

Comment: Yes, `backup.py` (and `view.py`) would have to be organized so that the parser creator code and the main execution code is importable.  Only the actual `parse_args` and calling of the main main code would be guarded by the 'if main'.  I suppose my code should have been organized in the same way - so it too could be imported!

Comment: An alternative is to use `parse_know_args` to find out which script you want to run, and then invoke `backup.py` or `view.py` as separate processes (with `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`), giving them the unknown argument strings.